# Wildcard Java string in list

Tags: java, string, wildcard

Is it possible to add a wildcard to a string in a list in Java?

I have a string, which has different endings (for example: Key(1), Key(2), Key(3), Key(4), Key(5) etc etc.)

Is it possible to somehow add a string to a list, with a wildcard, so I could just do something like:

```
list.add("Key*wildcard*");
```

And it would have all the different endings of the string?

Many thanks :-)

EDIT:
This is how I'll use it.

I'm coding something for a game, which has to check for a specific item. This item has charges, which defines the ending of the name of the item. The item is called "Games Necklace".

Now, I want to check, if the user has the item, and if not, it will buy one. I have a list of items required to do a certain task, but the Games Necklace changes name (from 8-1, so it can be either "Games Necklace(8), Games Necklace(7), Games Necklace(6) and down to 1). I want to check if the users has all the items in the list of items needed, but it should return true, if the user has any version of the necklace

Comment: What do you need to do with this list?  How are the Strings inside being used?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do here. add `Key` and get `Key(1), Key(2) ...` in the list? Maybe you should explain a bit more.

Comment: `All the different endings of the String` how do you define `All the different endings`?. Note that even a `List` has an limit of values it can hold.

Comment: Edited the original post :-)

Comment: @Jannik judging your edit i´d rather go with a class `Necklace` with a class member variable `charges`. This aproach rather uses the `OOP` principle and you wont have to care for different meanings of a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a wildcard string to the list, but then you have to implement the search in the list yourself, and you can't rely on `contains` to work for you, as it simply calls the `equals` method, and `equals` would not do what you need.

Here is a possible solution:

- Instead of using a List, use a List, and define the item as a regular expression.

  ```
  List<Pattern> requiredList = new List<>();
  requiredList.add(Pattern.compile("Sword");
  requiredList.add(Pattern.compile("Games Necklace\\(\\d+\\)");
  ```
- Write a method that matches all the patterns in the list against another collection. e.g.

  ```
  public static hasAll( List<Pattern> required, Collection<String> available) {
      for ( Pattern pat : available ) {
          boolean matched = false;
          for ( String item : needed ) {
              if ( pat.matcher(item).matches() ) {
                 matched = true;
                 break;
              }
          }
          if ( ! matched ) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```

Another option is to define your game items in their own class, not as strings. That class will have a "type" and a "display name". And you'll check it in the list using the type, which will be "Games Necklace" (for all of them), and display using the display name.

Answer (score 0):

No, as it doesn't make sense for a `String` to have multiple values (in Java at least). You could do it by making a class that represents your "multi-string" (of course change the mechanics oif it to fit your exact needs.

```
class MultiString {

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MultiString(String, prefix, int numValues) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numValues; i++) strings.add(prefix + String.valueOf(i));
    }

    public String get(int i) {
        return strings.get(i);
    }

}
```

Or you could just add several values to the list.

```
public void addStrings(List<String> list, String prefix, int numValues) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numValues; i++) list.add(prefix + String.valueOf(i));
}
```

More specific solutions can't be given  until we know your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i= 8; i>0;i--){
        list.add("Games Necklace("+i+")");
    }
```